# IE11 force scroll railing

Tags: css, scroll, overflow, internet-explorer-11

I am using the following CSS properties to swipe a bigger `div` inside another div `#screenviewport`:

```
#screenviewport {

    -ms-scroll-rails:railed;
    -ms-scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
    -ms-scroll-snap-points-x: snapInterval(0%, 100%);
    -ms-scroll-snap-points-y: snapInterval(0%, 100%);

    overflow:auto;

    width:640px; height; 480px; 
}
```

My problem is, while scroll-rails normally works (ie. you start swiping horizontally then vertical drag is blocked and viceversa), if you start swiping diagonally, the railing is not respected.

Can this be prevented?

Comment: "Specifies whether scrolling locks to the primary axis of motion." -- with a diagonal start, there is no primary axis of motion. It's worth noting that `railed` is the default value *anyway*.

Comment: Oh no ... another typical CSS duality that needs fragile JS workarounds.